# "GEOM_MIRROR: cancelling unmapped because of ada0"

Tags: freebsd

Recently upgraded my FreeBSD install to FreeBSD 9.1-stable from the 9-stable branch. I have two SATA hard drives (/dev/ada0, /dev/ada1) in a geom mirror, with nothing between : `[/dev/ada0, /dev/ada1] --> /dev/mirror/gm0`, which I then partition for root etc.

After upgrading from 9.0-stable to 9.1-stable, I found these messages on the console:

```
GEOM_MIRROR: cancelling unmapped because of ada0
GEOM_MIRROR: cancelling unmapped because of ada1
GEOM_MIRROR: Device mirror/gm0 launched (2/2).
```

Everything still seems to work, the mirror seems healthy and the machine works just fine, peformance is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [What's new to FreeBSD 10](https://wiki.freebsd.org/WhatsNew/FreeBSD10), 'unmapped vmio' buffers are coming to FreeBSD, as a performance benefit, and it would seem that the geom code in 9-stable has picked up some of the support for it.

According to commit [r252010](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/geom/mirror/g_mirror.c?r1=252010&r2=252009&pathrev=252010), the geom mirror provider is trying to use unmapped vmio, but can't because the ada provider for my SATA disks doesn't yet provide support for it:

```
/* A provider underneath us doesn't support unmapped */
if ((dp->flags & G_PF_ACCEPT_UNMAPPED) == 0) {
        G_MIRROR_DEBUG(0, "cancelling unmapped "
            "because of %s\n", dp->name);
        pp->flags &= ~G_PF_ACCEPT_UNMAPPED;
}
```

So it would seem that this error can be safely ignored, and will probably go away once universal unmapped vmio buffer support is integrated into FreeBSD